# Integer types in C and C++, and their interpretation by printf

Tags: c++, c, integer, printf

I have recently answered a question on SO, and found myself a bit uncertain of a few facts myself during the process, so I would like to get a second assertion of these facts:

1. Integer types in C and C++:

   - `char`: an integer value with the size of 1 byte.
   - `short`: an integer value with the size of 2 bytes.
   - `long`: an integer value with the size of 4 bytes.
   - `long long`: an integer value with the size of 8 bytes.

   The types `short`, `long` and `long long` are usually followed by `int`.

   It is not a must, however, and we can use them without the `int`.

   Alternatively, we can just state `int`, but that might be interpreted differently by different compilers.

   So to summarize this:

   - `short` is the same as `short int` but not necessarily the same as `int`.
   - `long` is the same as `long int` but not necessarily the same as `int`.
   - `long long` is the same as `long long int` but not necessarily the same as `int`.
   - On a given compiler, `int` is either `short int` or `long int` or `long long int`.
2. Printing an integer using `printf`:

   -`printf("%d"...)` reads an `int` value from the stack.

   -`printf("%ld"...)` reads a `long int` value from the stack.

   -`printf("%lld"...)` reads a `long long int` value from the stack.

   So:

   -`printf("%ld"...)` will read 4 bytes on any given platform.

   -`printf("%lld"...)` will read 8 bytes on any given platform.

   -`printf("%d"...)` will read 2 bytes or 4 bytes or 8 bytes, depending on the definition of `int` on the given platform.

**Are there any cavities in the description above?**

Thanks

Comment: "usually followed by `int`" - not in most modern coding styles.

Comment: `int` is not required to be the same size as any other integer type.

Comment: *The types short, long and long long are usually followed by int.* No.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: This comment is not very helpful. Is the specific statement wrong? If yes, what is wrong with it? Please read the two statements that follow it.

Comment: Why not, um, read the standards?

Comment: Note that plain `char` is a distinct type from both `signed char` and `unsigned char` and may be signed or unsigned.  It will have the same range as one of the other two types, but is still technically a different type from either.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I did not relate to `signed`/`unsigned`, as it has no "impact" within the question whatsoever... However, now that you mention it, are you suggesting that `char` can be something other than `signed char` or `unsigned char`???

Comment: Like I said, `char` is a different type from both `signed char` and `unsigned char` (though the range of valid values for `char` is the same as either the range of either `signed char` or `unsigned char`).  Plain `char` may be signed or unsigned.  Yes: plain `char` is different again.  There are three distinct char types — `char` and `signed char` and `unsigned char`.  See ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.2.5 Types, ¶3, 4, 5, 6, 14, 15 in particular.

Comment: So on a given compiler, I might have different behavior for each of these three types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of fairly major holes.

A `char` always occupies 1 byte. That's the *only* type for which the size is guaranteed though. All the others are basically 1 or more bytes, and large enough to hold a specified range of values (16 bits for `short` or `int`, 32 bits for `long` and 64 bits for `long long`).

In other words the sizes you've given are pretty common, but not guaranteed.

With `printf`:

- "%d" specifies an `int`
- "%ld" specifies a `long int`
- "%lld" specifies a `long long int`.

As above, each of these has a specified minimum range, but not a required size.

Likewise, the standard doesn't actually specify that the machine have a stack (and a few, such as IBM mainframes and old Crays, don't), though if you consider only abstract behavioral requirements, then what you get is certainly LIFO (stack-like) requirements.

Comment: Although `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition, there are systems where `CHAR_BIT == 16` rather than 8, especially in the DSP world.

Comment: Yes, and technically on such systems a byte is 16 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Many questions....
Many answers....

OP: `long`: an integer value with the size of 4 bytes.
A: `long` is an integer with the minimum range of -2147483647 to +2147483647, thus it needs at *least* 32 bits.

OP: `long long`: an integer value with the size of 8 bytes.
A: `long long` is an integer with the minimum range of -9223372036854775807 to +9223372036854775807, thus it needs at *least* 64 bits.

OP: The types `short`, `long` and `long long` are usually followed by `int`.
A: I see `short`, `long` and `long long` more often by themselves then with a following `int`, unless it is in a pedantic usage like the C spec.
A: Further (not my opinion): `short int i` is the same as `short i`. `long int i` is the same as `long i`.  `long int i` is the same as `long i`.
A: Further: `short signed int i` is the same as `short i`.   `short`, `signed`, `int` may occur in any order with the same result.

OP: It is not a must, however, and we can use them without the `int`.
A: Yes. See above.

OP: Alternatively, we can just state `int`, but that might be interpreted differently by different compilers.
A: The size/range may change, but `short` is the same as `signed short`is the same as `signed short int`is the same as `signed int`.  This holds true with 'long' and 'long long', but not with 'char'.

OP: `short` is the same as `short int` but not necessarily the same as `int`.
A: Yes.

OP: `long` is the same as `long int` but not necessarily the same as `int`.
A: Yes.

OP: long long is the same as long long int but not necessarily the same as int.
A: Yes.

OP: On a given compiler, `int` is either `short int` or `long int` or `long long int`.
A: No.  All 4 may be different size/range.

OP: -printf("%d"...) reads an `int` value from the stack.
OP: -printf("%ld"...) reads a `long int` value from the stack.
OP: -printf("%lld"...) reads a `long long int` value from the stack.
A: Yes - other mechanisms other than "stack" exist.  Better to think of the `int` coming from a variadic parameter.

OP: -printf("%ld"...) will read 4 bytes on any given platform.
OP: -printf("%lld"...) will read 8 bytes on any given platform.
OP: -printf("%d"...) will read 2 bytes or 4 bytes or 8 bytes, depending on the definition of int on the given platform.
A: No.  The size of a `long` is at least as much as `int`.  The size of a `long long` is at least as much as `long`.  The number of bytes read is platform dependent.

The definition of a "byte" in C is "addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment".  So `sizeof(char)` --> 1 or in `C` parlance 1 byte, whether its 8, 9, 32, or whatever bit size.

In the larger world many folks consider a "byte" to be 8 bits.  These two "byte" definition can confuse.    When talking `C`, I prefer to say something like "The size of a short is 4" meaning `sizeof(int)` --> 4 or twice as much as `char`, without using the word "byte".

Comment: Some problems with the answer above: 1. I did not mention `signed`/`unsigned` for a reason. It has no "impact" within the question whatsoever. 2. Every statement you make after "IMO your suggestion is false" is specified within the question, so are these statements true or false? 3. Are you suggesting that `int` may be something other than `short int` or `long int` or `long long int`?

Comment: Yes, int may be different from short, long, and long long.

Comment: @barak manos  1) I did not mention `unsigned` either.  `signed` is mentioned as with `int`, etc. it is optional without changing the type. 2) Edit to be more clear.  3) Yes, all 4 may differ.

Comment: You could have, for example, 16-bit `short`, 32-bit `int`, 64-bit `long`, 128-bit `long long` and 256-bit `intmax_t`.  I don't know of a system that does that, but it is far from impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your assertions are not correct, as they vary from platform to platform.  To know with certitude the width of your types, open up your `limits.h` and `float.h` files.  You can also use the `sizeof` operator.

Keep in mind that a `char` is always one byte, regardless of how many bits it has.  That is, on some machines a `char` is 8 bits and on another a `char` is 16 bits.  In each case, it is considered one byte.  Other types are multiples of `char`.

Comment: Thanks, but I did not ask **how** to calculate the size of a given variable.

Comment: @barakmanos You didn't directly, but your assumption that certain types are certain sizes (a `short` is always two bytes) is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot say with certainty, what the size of any of the integer types are for a given platform without consulting [limits.h](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/limits.h) and, possibly, [stdint.h](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h). However, you can be sure that the `printf` format string associates the correct patterns with the correctly sized integers passed on the stack for a given implementation.